# Making an image responsive while preserving coordinates in a react app

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a React application where I need to utilize specific areas of an image by providing coordinates. While making this image responsive by adjusting its width, I encountered an issue. The responsiveness distorts the coordinates, causing the intended clickable areas to malfunction. I'm seeking guidance on how to make the image responsive while keeping the coordinates intact.

Here's a breakdown of the problem I'm facing:

Image Coordinates: I have an image with defined coordinates for clickable regions. These coordinates are essential for triggering specific actions when those areas are clicked.

Responsiveness Requirement: I need the image to be responsive, adapting to various screen sizes. Adjusting the image width seems to be the logical choice for achieving this responsiveness.

Coordinate Distortion: When I adjust the image width to make it responsive, the original coordinates no longer match the intended clickable areas. This results in the failure of triggering the desired actions when those regions are clicked.

I'm looking for advice on the best approach to tackle this issue. How can I make the image responsive without compromising the accuracy of the coordinates? Is there a way to adjust the image width while preserving the mapping of coordinates to clickable areas?

```
const [selectedIdentifier, setSelectedIdentifier] = useState(null);
const handleClick = (event) => {
    const identifier = event.target.getAttribute("data-identifier");
    setSelectedIdentifier(identifier);
    console.log("Identifier of the clicked area:", identifier);
  };

<div>
  <img useMap="#form" src={src} alt={`Image`} />
   <map onClick={handleClick} name="form">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1025,10,1158,52" data-identifier="1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="85,56,619,202" data-identifier="2" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="624,56,1163,202" data-identifier="3" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="86,204,621,352" data-identifier="4" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="621,204,1160,352" data-identifier="5" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="87,358,622,453" data-identifier="6" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="626,358,1161,453" data-identifier="7" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="86,458,624,551" data-identifier="8" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="85,555,623,653" data-identifier="9" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="624,455,1160,653" data-identifier="10"/>
  </map>
</div>
```

I wrote a wrapper css and gave it a max width, but its coordinates have changed and I can't trigger the area I want.